# Discrepancy in nlme::lme output

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I've noticed a discrepancy in the SEs of the fixed effect estimates given by the `nlme::lme` function. Specifically, the SEs in the summary output differ from the square root of the diagonal entries of the estimated variance-covariance matrix . Here is an example:

```
library(nlme)

fit=lme(Yield~Time+Variety,Alfalfa,random=~1|Block,method="ML")
```

The summary output gives the following SEs:

```
> summary(fit)
...
Fixed effects:  Yield ~ Variety 
                   Value  Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)    1.5716667 0.11013218 64 14.270731  0.0000
VarietyLadak   0.0945833 0.07947391 64  1.190118  0.2384
VarietyRanger -0.0191667 0.07947391 64 -0.241169  0.8102
...
```

The estimated variance-covariance matrix gives somewhat different values:

```
> sqrt(diag(fit$varFix))
  (Intercept)  VarietyLadak VarietyRanger 
   0.10781334    0.07780059    0.07780059
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation in `help("summary.lme")` answers your question:

> `adjustSigma`
>
> an optional logical value. If `TRUE` and the estimation method used to
> obtain `object` was maximum likelihood, the residual standard error is
> multiplied by $\sqrt{n_{obs}/(n_{obs} - n_{par})}$, converting it to a
> REML-like estimate. This argument is only used when a single fitted
> object is passed to the function. Default is `TRUE`.

This adjustment is also applied to the parameters' standard errors. If you set `adjustSigma = FALSE` you get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works.